# Python3 re.search() fails with binary string

Tags: python-3.x, hex, byte, xor

I've been reading XOR questions for hours now, but have yet to find one that addresses my problem. It's probably an issue of using the wrong terminology, but perhaps someone can help me out.

I have a 32 bit Windows executable that I read into a binary string

```
with open('file.exe', 'rb') as f:
    blob = f.read()
```

No issues there. However, there is a section of the file that is XOR encoded with a single-byte key, which I would like to decode. I don't know the value of the XOR, but I do have a known section of the decoded data that I can look for, so I have an XOR brute force:

```
for x in range(0, 255):
   known_string = bytearray('\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00'.encode())
   for i in range(len(known_string)):
       known_string[i] ^= x
   if re.search(bytes(known_string), blob):
       return x
```

This works in many cases; however, if the value of `x` is above 31, I get the ASCII representation of the XOR-ed bytes, rather than `\x..`, which causes the `re.search()` to fail.

In this case, the XOR value should be 0x50. If I XOR the known string with that value, I expect to get

`bytearray(b'\x50\x51\x50\x51\x50')`.

Instead, I get

`bytearray(b'23232')`.

I need the first representation so that I can search for it in `blob`, but nothing I have tried yields the expected result.

**UPDATE FOR MORE CONTEXT**

Per the answer below, the representation of the bytes is not my issue. However, I have a second sequence of known bytes that are separated by 3 unknown bytes, which is why I'm using a regex search. If I implement the solution below, I have something that looks like this:

```
for x in range(256):
    sequence_1 = bytes(byte ^ x for byte in b'\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00')
    sequence_2 = bytes(byte ^ x for byte in b'\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00')

    full_sequence = sequence_1 + b'...' + sequence_2
    if re.search(full_sequence, blob):
        return x
```

In this case, with an XOR value of `0x50`, `full_sequence` is

`b'PQPQP...PRPQP'`

The actual string in the blob is

`b'...PQPQPRPPPRPQP...'`

It is my understanding that re.search() should match the sequence to this string, but it does not return any matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works in many cases; however, if the value of x is above 31, I get the ASCII representation of the XOR-ed bytes, rather than \x.., which causes the re.search() to fail.

Why would the way the byte string is *represented* affect `re.search()`?

It's merely a representation. Under the hood the values are the same. All of these 0-to-255 byte strings are the same:

```py
byte_string = bytes(i for i in range(256))
byte_string_default_representation = b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
byte_string_hex = b"\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3a\x3b\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f\x40\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4d\x4e\x4f\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x5b\x5c\x5d\x5e\x5f\x60\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff"
byte_string_oct = b"\000\001\002\003\004\005\006\007\010\011\012\013\014\015\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\032\033\034\035\036\037\040\041\042\043\044\045\046\047\050\051\052\053\054\055\056\057\060\061\062\063\064\065\066\067\070\071\072\073\074\075\076\077\100\101\102\103\104\105\106\107\110\111\112\113\114\115\116\117\120\121\122\123\124\125\126\127\130\131\132\133\134\135\136\137\140\141\142\143\144\145\146\147\150\151\152\153\154\155\156\157\160\161\162\163\164\165\166\167\170\171\172\173\174\175\176\177\200\201\202\203\204\205\206\207\210\211\212\213\214\215\216\217\220\221\222\223\224\225\226\227\230\231\232\233\234\235\236\237\240\241\242\243\244\245\246\247\250\251\252\253\254\255\256\257\260\261\262\263\264\265\266\267\270\271\272\273\274\275\276\277\300\301\302\303\304\305\306\307\310\311\312\313\314\315\316\317\320\321\322\323\324\325\326\327\330\331\332\333\334\335\336\337\340\341\342\343\344\345\346\347\350\351\352\353\354\355\356\357\360\361\362\363\364\365\366\367\370\371\372\373\374\375\376\377"
print(byte_string == byte_string_default_representation == byte_string_hex == byte_string_oct)
```

Output:

```py
True
```

Here's how I would write it.

```py
# Your range(0, 255) loop misses 255.
# No need for .encode. Just make it a bytes literal by appending b.
# A generator comprehension might be simpler than using a bytearray.
# No need for regex, just use the in operator.
for x in range(256):
    known_string = bytes(byte^x for byte in b'\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00')
    if known_string in blob:
        return x
```

---

I could not replicate your not getting any matches.

Using your blob and sequences, I ran into an exception: `error: nothing to repeat`. While `x` was `0x28`, `full_sequence` was `b'()()(...(*()('` which is an absurd pattern. So then I wrapped the call to `re.search()` in a try-except block, and I noticed it found 2 matches. One was absurd, when `x` was `0x7c`, `full_sequence` was `b'|}|}|...|~|}|'`.

Instead of regex, try using `bytes.find()` twice. It returns `-1` if it does not find a match. The 2nd and 3rd arguments are the start and end indexes for where to find a match.

```py
import re

blob = b'PQPQPRPPPRPQP'

for x in range(256):
    sequence_1 = bytes(byte ^ x for byte in b'\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00')
    sequence_2 = bytes(byte ^ x for byte in b'\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00')

    full_sequence = sequence_1 + b'...' + sequence_2
    try:
        if re.search(full_sequence, blob):
            print(f"re.search match found! {x=:x}, {full_sequence=}")
    except Exception:
        continue

for x in range(256):
    sequence_1 = bytes(byte ^ x for byte in b'\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00')
    index = blob.find(sequence_1)
    if index != -1:
        sequence_2 = bytes(byte ^ x for byte in b'\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00')
        index += len(sequence_1)+3
        if blob.find(sequence_2, index, index+len(sequence_2)) != -1:
            print(f"blob.find match found! {x=:x}, {sequence_1=}, {sequence_1=}")
```

Output:

```py
re.search match found! x=50, full_sequence=b'PQPQP...PRPQP'
re.search match found! x=7c, full_sequence=b'|}|}|...|~|}|'
blob.find match found! x=50, sequence_1=b'PQPQP', sequence_1=b'PQPQP'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It turns out I misunderstood the representation of the data. However, it also turns out that I have 2 known sequences that are separated by 3 unknown bytes. So, if I use your suggestion above for both strings, I have ```known_string1``` and ```known_string2```. To check them against the binary, I use ```re.search(known_string1 + b'...' + known_string2, blob)``` and it comes back with zero results, even though I can clearly see that the sequence exists in the blob. So the original question was misguided, but the result is the same.

Comment: No problemo. I could not replicate your issue with `re.search()` not returning a match when it should. Check my updated answer. I recommended using `bytes.find` instead of regex, because regex returns false positives due to absurd patterns generated by xoring the byte string.

Comment: I cannot explain why ```re.search()``` doesn't find the string, but ```bytes.find()``` did the trick. I implemented the following:

```start_pos = data.find(start1) 

if start_pos and data.find(start2) == start_pos + len(start1) + 3:
    return x```

And that returns the expected result.

Comment: Keep in mind `start_pos` will be `-1` if no match is found, and `-1` evaluates to `True`. Change the if statement to: `if start_pos != -1 and data.find(start2) == start_pos + len(start1) + 3:`